# Code Rewite for tuple and if else statements by using LINQ

Tags: linq, if-statement, null

In my C# application i am using linq. I need a help what is the syntax for if-elseif- using linq in single line. Data, RangeDate are the inputs. Here is the code:

```
var Date1 = RangeData.ToList();
int record =0;
foreach (var tr in Date1)
{
    int id =0;
    if (tr.Item1 != null && tr.Item1.port != null)
    {
        id = tr.Item1.port.id;
    }
    else if (tr.Item2 != null && tr.Item2.port != null)
    {
        id = tr.Item2.port.id;
    }
    if (id >0)
    {
         if(Data.Trygetvalue(id, out cdat)
          { 
         // Do some operation. (var cdata = SumData(id, tr.item2.port.Date)
         record ++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can select the trs which id is > 0 using Linq (for instance `Date1.Where(tr => tr > 3)`, but what you do with them inside `if (id > 0) {...}` has nothing to do with Linq. BTW the `else if` block condition will always be false since at this stage, tr <= 0.

Comment: You can use @Roxtar's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following code:

```
var count = RangeData.Select(x => new { Id = x.Item1?.port?.id ?? x.Item2?.port?.id ?? 0, Item = x })
                     .Count(x =>
                     {
                         int? cdate = null; // change int to your desired type over here
                         if (x.Id > 0 && Data.Trygetvalue(x.Id, out cdat))
                         {
                             // Do some operation. (var cdata = SumData(x.Id, x.Item.Item2.port.Date)

                             return true;
                         }
                         return false;
                     });
```

**Edit:**

@D Stanley is completely right, LINQ is wrong tool over here. You can refactor few bits of your code though:

```
var Date1 = RangeData.ToList();
int record =0;
foreach (var tr in Date1)
{
    int? cdat = null; // change int to your desired type over here
    int id = tr.Item1?.port?.id ?? tr.Item2?.port?.id ?? 0;
    if (id >0 && Data.Trygetvalue(id, out cdat))
    { 
         // Do some operation. (var cdata = SumData(id, tr.Item2.port.Date)
         record ++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think your code example is false, your record variable is initialized to 0 on each loop so increment it is useless .

I suppose that you want to count records in your list which have an id, you can achieve this with one single `Count()` :

```
var record = Date1.Count(o => (o.Item1?.port?.id ?? o.Item2?.port?.id) > 0);
```

Comment: Question Updated @Roxtar

Comment: What was updated ? You're still initializing your record variable inside the foreach statement, and this makes no sense.

Comment: @Roxtar Updated the question, I initialized the record variable outside the for-each loop.

Comment: Okay, so in my answer you have the lambda which counts records according to your code snippet. For `// Do some operation.` it depends on what you want to do here.

Comment: i need to do some operation ( i need to call other function) before i count the records. @Roxtar

Answer (score 0):

Linq is not the right tool here. Linq is for *converting* or *querying* a collection. You are looping over a collection and "doing some operation". Depending on what that operation is, trying to shoehorn it into a Linq statement will be harder to understand to an outside reader, difficult to debug, and hard to maintain.

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the loop that you have. As you can tell from the other answers, it's difficult to wedge all of the information you have into a "single-line" statement *just* to use Linq.